# How to configure dialog for multiple folder (or files) picker?

Tags: c#

I am using this lib https://github.com/augustoproiete/ookii-dialogs-wpf for dialog presentation.

I am using such dialog for pick singe folder

```
        private void Btn_path_to_save_processed_clip_folder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.VistaFolderBrowserDialog
            {
                Description = "Select where to save processed clip folder",
                SelectedPath = m_TbClipSaveDirectory,
                UseDescriptionForTitle = true
            };

            if (dialog.ShowDialog(Application.Current.MainWindow).GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                m_TbClipSaveDirectory = dialog.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
```

Question is - is there an option to pick a few folders at once?

Or maybe some others ways?

Comment: Does using CTRL and selecting the desired folders not work?

Comment: I played around with Ookii dialogs and I can't find any "out of the box" way to do what you seek.  If you use the VistaOpenFileDialog class, then it is possible to select multiple folders, but then when you click the "Open" button, it browses into the first of the selected folders, instead of closing the dialog.  Perhaps it is possible to create your own class that inherits VistaFileDialog and design it to do what you want, but I am not sure.  You might want to seek a different library than Ookii if you want to be able to select multiple folders.

Comment: @TonyPulokas any suggestions, which lib?

Comment: @Aleksey Timoshchenko, sorry, I only have experience with Ookii.

Comment: There's this old page that looks promising (see 2nd image): http://www.ssware.com/articles/folderbrowserdialog-unmasked-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-the-folder-browser-component-from-dotnet-framework.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I made it with NuGet

1) Right click on project -> Manage NuGet packages -> in browse tab fill `WindowsAPICodePack-Shell` and set up into needed package

2) Create dialog

```
using var dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog
{
    IsFolderPicker = true,
    Multiselect = true
};
```

Here you can see two settings `IsFolderPicker` - in order to chose only folders not a files and `Multiselect` - for multiselection

and eventually result

```
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
{
    var folders = dialog.FileNames;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", folders));
}
```

Result is:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any picker gives multiple folder by default.There can be multiple file in same folder option. Why don't you put an option saying upload more if they say yes show them dialog box again.and keep showing them from the list of predefined folders

```
var folderpath = new List<string>() { "c:", "d:" };
```

Now you can save the index of previous path and show next path

```
var static foldertoshow =0;
    m_TbClipSaveDirectory= folderpath [foldertoshow ];
    foldertoshow ++;
     SelectedPath = m_TbClipSaveDirectory,
```

next time

```
m_TbClipSaveDirectory= folderpath [foldertoshow ];
    foldertoshow ++;
     SelectedPath = m_TbClipSaveDirectory,
```